# Using the conception of 'reliable, unchanging' does 'truth' exist?

Tags: logic, truth, proof

An 'archaic' definition for TRUE,TRUTH implies *constancy, reliability, unchanging, fidelity*.

Using this concept of TRUTH is the following valid?

- There exists either that which is TRUE or that which is not TRUE.
- It cannot be TRUE that only non-TRUE things exist.
- Therefore TRUTH exists.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your definition of "truth." Can you cite a source?

Comment: @James - I'm having a little trouble finding a source that matches the concept.   If I said _ever reliable, never changing_ would that provide a better connection to the concept?  Very similar to a constant in programming in the sense that it can be relied on 'not to have changed'.

Comment: @James - In the first edition of the Oxford English Dictionary the primary definition uses the concepts: faithfulness, consistency, steadfast, fidelity... This is virtually the same as those concepts used in the question.

Answer (score 2):

> There exists either that which is TRUE or that which is not TRUE. It
>   cannot be TRUE that only non-TRUE things exist. Therefore TRUTH
>   exists.

I say the conclusion is valid. Here is how I would reason it through.

1. Either T or not-T.
2. “All things are not-T” is false. Thus, by implication, its contradictory statement is true: “Some things are not not-T”.
3. Thus T. There must be at least one true thing if the second premise is false. Everything need not be true, but at least one thing must be.